# Android flash website in webview and back button force closes application

Tags: java, android, flash, webview

I am trying to make a little app that shows Timetable, but to make it easier I want to show flash website on fragment webview. How can I do this?

I have tried to enable plugin, but it doesn't enable flashplayer. What would be the best solution to show it in the webview or just in app?

Comment: Android 4.1+ does not support flash player any longer.  Prior to Android 4.1 there is still no guarantee the user has it installed.  Though it can be sideloaded still on newer Android versions, it's very unlikely the average user will have it installed

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file on application tag add this property

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

If not working then try setting the below property to your webView.

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

Note: The above fix does not work in all android phones.